# Loading images from Facebook in Flash Builder

Tags: flash, image, facebook, load, facebook-fql

I'm doing a Facebook App where I'd like to pull out all the possible images from a user's album.

What I'm trying to do at the moment is a fql query so that i can find all the images that belong to that specific user. it goes something like that:

```
        protected function loadFromFacebook(event:MouseEvent):void {

            var fql:String = "select src_small from photo where owner = me()";              
            Facebook.fqlQuery(fql, handleGetPhotosResponse);

        }


        private function handleGetPhotosResponse(event:Object, fail:Object):void {
            if (event != null){

                facebookPhotos = new ArrayCollection(event as Array);

            } 
        }
```

I store this images in an array collection but I don't know how to proceed after that. How can I load those images into, say, a Tile List or a Loader?

Any help would be much appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are a TileList component named 'tList', you would do a 'for loop' on the arraycollection and create a new image, and add it to the TileList on each iteration.

```
// I am not sure if the array collection contains photo urls, 
// but this is the general idea ...
// you may need to build the url with fb graph ...
for ( var i:uing = 0; i < facebookPhotos.length; i++ ) 
{
    var img:Image = new Image();
    img.load( facebookPhotos.getItemAt(i) ); // url here
    tList.addChild( img );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do a handler function that receive a result object and a fail object.
the result object is an array of fields that you requested with the fql.

```
    protected function loadFromFacebook(event:MouseEvent):void {

        var fql:String = "select src_small from photo where owner = me()";              
        Facebook.fqlQuery(fql, handleGetPhotosResponse);

    }

    protected function handleGetPhotosResponse(result:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            photosList = new ArrayCollection();
            var photo:Object;
            for (var i:Object in result)
            {
                photo = new Object();
                photo.imgSrc = result[i].src_small;
                photosList.addItem(photo);
            }
            provider = photosList;
        }
```